# Fix vertical space for all display equations for all possibilities

Tags: math-mode, spacing, vertical-alignment

I'm having a much difficult requirement which I explained below in details (refer the screen shots) and the tags are as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{mathtools}%to load amsmath

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\newbox\eqnskipbox%
\newdimen\eqnskipdimen%

\setbox\eqnskipbox=\hbox{\bgroup$\displaystyle\dfrac{\int}{\int}\displaystyle\sum^{i=1}_{j=1}$\vphantom{$\displaystyle\dfrac{\int}{\int}$}\vphantom{$\displaystyle\sum^{i=1}_{j=1}$}\vphantom{hy}\egroup}%
\eqnskipdimen=\ht\eqnskipbox%

\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{10}{13}%
\advance\eqnskipdimen by -11\p@%
   \abovedisplayskip \eqnskipdimen%
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ %\@plus3\p@%
   \belowdisplayshortskip 3.5\p@ %\@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@%
   \belowdisplayskip \eqnskipdimen%
   \let\@listi\@listI}%
\normalsize
\let\@bls\baselineskip
\makeatother

In business, planning is a process that helps a firm determine text
for dummy a course of action in order to achieve future objectives, given limited resources. 
\[
a+b=c
\]
This is for testing
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b}\frac{\int}{\int}
\end{align}

A typical financial planning process begins with evaluating the market environment and past performance in order to identify business strategic and operating priorities.
\begin{equation}
\sum^{i=1}_{j=1}
\end{equation}

Next we define expectations. Given an initial state $s_{0}$, a feasible
plan $\pi $ from $s_{0},$ and the stochastic kernels $P_{t},$ $t=1,\ldots,T,$
define a probability measure on $\mathcal{S}^{t}$ as dummy text
\begin{align}
\mu ^{t}\left( s_{0},B;\pi \right) =&\int_{B_{1}}\ldots
\int_{B_{t-1}}\int_{B_{t}}P_{t}\left( s_{t-1},\pi _{t-1}\left(
s^{t-1}\right)\! ;\ ds_{t}\right)  \notag\\
&\times P_{t-1}\left( s_{t-2},\pi _{t-2}\left( s^{t-2}\right)
;\ ds_{t-1}\right) \cdots\ P_{1}\left( s_{0},\pi _{0};\ ds_{1}\right)\!,  \label{mu0t}
\end{align}
for any $B=B_{1}\times \cdots\times $ $B_{t}\in \mathcal{S}^{t}$, where we set $\pi_{0}({s^{0})}=\pi_{0}$ and $s^{0}=s_0$ by convention.

\end{document}
```

I need to fix the `above/below` space for all `display math` should be as `20pt base to base` for all occurrences, e.g., for simple math, fraction, summation symbol, etc. Please refer the below screenshot for more clarification:

[image]

Expecting all your valuable suggestions...

Can any one suggests to achieve this? Please...

Comment: possibly unrelated but `\def\@mathmargin{\z@}` would break `amsmath`  `\@mathmargin` is a length register not a macro

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I realized that after posting the `MWE`, sorry...

Comment: There is basically no sensible way (in one pass) of specifying lengths from the baseline of a subcript to the baseline of a following expression. Why do you want this?

Comment: This is an one of a must requirement for an author, sorry, I have to fix it per his requirement and he told that no need to balance the pages at the bottom due to this...

Comment: It really is a nonsensical requirement, consider a more complicated expression with multiple fractions and subscripts, just working out which is the "lowest baseline" of the math expression is not at all easy or well defined, and that is before you try to use that to adjust the space.

Comment: Really I'm struggling a lot, till date I fixed this by giving manual `\vspace` and the time killing me like anything, that's why I raised this issue...if possible, can you help me? please...

Comment: It involves a lot manual work in any case as even if you calculate the space with \pdfsavepos you would have to decide for every equation which part is the reference point and insert markers there. So tell the author that it costs quite some hours.

Comment: @MadyYuvi no sorry there is no way of doing this in the amount of work that is reasonable for an answer on this site.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I do not think that the requirement leads to good typography at all, the spacing of `xxx \[a=b\] yyy` should be the same as  `xxx \[a^2=b_1\] yyy` but you would adjust the space above to put 20pt between baseline of xxx and baseline of 2 and below to put 20pt  between baseline of 1 and baseline of yyy  this is going to make the spacing look very uneven.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Happy morning, I've spoken with the author regarding the uneven space as you mentioned, but he said that `it's fine, please proceed what I asked before...`, so has to meet his requirement, is there any way? please

Comment: @MadyYuvi as I say it requires far more work than is reasonable to ask anyone to do for free or post to this site, especially as the result is typographically poor so probably not usable for any other document, so sorry no, I won't be answering this question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no issues, if you can then its very fine....and thanks for your patience...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Could you please use existing tags instead of inventing new ones?  You do this for *a lot* of your questions.

Comment: @HenriMenke Sorry, will take care in future...